# C++ Cast float* to glm::vec3

Tags: c++, casting, glm-math

How can I cast an array of floats int the form `float*` to `glm::vec3`? I thought I had done it before but I lost my hdd. I tried a few C-style and `static_cast`s but I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [glm documentation](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/tree/0.9.5/doc) tells you how to cast from `vec3` to a `float*`.

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
glm::vec3 aVector(3);
glm::mat4 someMatrix(1.0);
glUniform3fv(uniformLoc, 1, glm::value_ptr(aVector));
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformMatrixLoc,
       1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(someMatrix));
```

You use `glm::value_ptr`.

The documentation doesn't say this explicitly, however it seems clear that glm intends these types to be 'layout compatible' with  arrays, so that they can be used directly with OpenGL functions. If so then you can cast from an array to vec3 using the following cast:

```
float arr[] = { 1.f, 0.f, 0.f };
vec3<float> *v = reinterpret_cast<vec3<float>*>(arr);
```

You should probably wrap this up in your own utility function because you don't want to be scattering this sort of cast all over your codebase.

Comment: To sell it to your pedantic theoretical software engineer colleague you could add a `static_assert(sizeof(glm::vec3) == 3 * sizeof(float))` somewhere for extra safety in the unlikely event that the `vec3` implementation will change from being just a `float[3]` wrapper.

Answer (score 23):

From `float*` to `vec3`:

```
float data[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
glm::vec3 vec = glm::make_vec3(data);
```

From `vec3` to `float*`:

```
glm::vec3 vec(1, 2, 3);
float* data = glm::value_ptr(vec);
```

In both cases, do not forget to `#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>`.

Comment: This, however, is a conversion, not a cast and will likely allocate new memory.

Comment: It does not allocate new memory. How could it? If it returned something from the stack that would be invalid since it is just returning a pointer, and if it returned something from the heap the documentation would tell you to clean it up. The only alternative is to use `atexit` or something which is a bad practice that you don't normally see in libraries. Also I checked the code and it just returns the address of the first data member.

Answer (score 2):

```
glm::vec3 construct_vec3(float *value)
{
    return glm::vec3(value[0], value[1], value[2]);
}
```