# Is there any way to reference floats as a glm::vec3

Tags: c++, glm-math

I have floats in a context

```
float* floats = calloc(3, sizeof(float));
float& x = floats[0];
float& y = floats[1];
float& z = floats[2];
```

How do I assign them to a `glm::vec3` such that I can perform operations on them? Is it really a matter of:

```
glm::vec3 vertex = { x, y, z };
// Transform and Rotate vertex
X = vertex.x;
y = vertex.y;
z = vertex.z;
```

Or is there a way I can bind the values to the `vec3`

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858311/c-cast-float-to-glmvec3

Comment: Useful I can possibly use `vec3* vertex = reinterpret_cast<vec3>(floats);`

Comment: @Śaeunacreáť Don't do that. You'll have more trouble with that.

Why do you have `float`s and not `glm::vec3` in your code when you want to use them in the first place?

Comment: @Raildex because the floats are stored as arrays of floats in the underlying code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting to a `vec3` worked as expected, with the underlying floats changing when I changed the `vec3` values.

```
vec3& vertex = (*reinterpret_cast<vec3*>(floats));
vertex.x = 1;
assert(floats[0] == vertex.x);
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` will cause undefined behavior

Comment: Seems to pass `valgrind` all fine!

Comment: `valgrind` has nothing to do with undefined behavior

Comment: How do you mean `undefined behaviour`?